# How to enable the draft item security on document library inside app web of SharePoint app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, draft

as we know, there are draft item security inside SharePoint (see [the link](http://www.novolocus.com/2009/04/09/content-approval-statuses/)) which would allow the item to stay at the draft status and it would prevent the content available to all users. I created a SharePoint hosted app with a document library. However I didn't see the library setting at the document library at app web at all even I am an administrator user on the parent host site, thus I am not able to enable such setting.  Just wonder if anyone knows how I could enable the draft item security in this case then. Can I enable it programmatically?

Comment: The question makes almost zero sense and the provided link redirects to some survey spam site. If you want to manage the Draft visibility settings for a list, you can get and set the DraftVersionVisibility (enum) property. //0=Reader, 1=Author, 2=Approver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set it with CSOM by setting the `EnableModeration` member to true:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{
    var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('List Name');
    list.EnableModeration = true;

    // Optional, set approval workflow for content approval
    list.EnableMinorVersions = true;    // Below will throw error if this is not enabled
    list.DefaultContentApprovalWorkflowId = Guid.Parse ("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");

    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

If you're using JSOM:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var web = ctx.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Your list');

list.set_enableModeration(true);
list.set_enableMinorVersions(true);
list.set_defaultContentApprovalWorkflowId("guid");
ctx.executeQueryAsync(success, error);
```

If you use JSOM, you might want to double check my syntax, I might've messed it up.

Answer (score 0):

while using JSOM, below thing works perfectly(there is some issue with **wjervis** code , but thanks for your hint): pass site title in button click and call the function.

```
var clientContext=null;
var web=null;
var oList = null;

function GetData(title)
{
    var url = 'some url' + title;
    clientContext=new SP.ClientContext(url);    
    web = clientContext.get_web();  
    oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("list name");
    //important
    oList.set_draftVersionVisibility(0);
    oList.update(); 
    clientContext.load(oList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
 }
function onQuerySucceeded() {
        if(this.oList.get_draftVersionVisibility() < 1)
            alert('Versioning set successfully');
        else
            alert('Some issue , please check again');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```